# Change location of error message for hidden field

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

**Blade**

```
{!! Form::open(array('method' => 'POST', 'id' => 'createUserForm')) !!}
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    {{ Form::hidden('SelectedRoleID') }}
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="SelectRole">Select Role</label>    
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div id="tree1"></div>
        </div>
    </div>    
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-4">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                {!! trans("Common.Button_Save") !!}
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

**JQuery Validate**

```
$("form#" + createUserForm).validate({
    ignore: "",
    rules: {
        SelectedRoleID: {
            required:   true,
            number:     true,
            min:        1
        }
    },
    messages: {
        SelectedRoleID: {
            required:   "{!! trans('Role.RequiredRole') !!}"
        }
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        debugger;
        return;

    }
});
```

**Error Message shown in red**

[image]

**Question**

Can I show the JQuery Validate message under `<div id="tree1"></div>`? Actually that is hidden field

Comment: Can you try,$("#tree1").addClass("hello").text("Error Condition"); where .hello{
visibility:visible;
color:red;

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("form#" + createUserForm).validate({
    ignore: "",
    rules: {
        SelectedRoleID: {
            required:   true,
            number:     true,
            min:        1
        }
    },
    messages: {
        SelectedRoleID: {
            required:   "{!! trans('Role.RequiredRole') !!}"
        }
    },
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        if(element[0].name === "SelectedRoleID") {
            error.insertAfter($('#tree1'));
        }
        else {
            $(error[0]).insertAfter($(element[0]));
        }
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        debugger;
        return;

    }
});
```

Comment: put a condition on that field if that field called for validation execute showing message statement

Comment: you just have to put condition for only one field only